# AD powershell query failing with "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception" error

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2019

When trying to query AD from new windows 2019 Server with different domain, it is throwing below error
"**get-aduser : A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception**"

[image]

Same query from same user is working fine from Windows 2012R2 server.

**Workaround applied**

1. Working if trying from specific Domain Controller.

   > Issue: we need to hardcode domain controller rather than directory name
2. When trying with "-credential (get-credential /username)" (with same user)it is working fine

   > Issue: It is prompting for credential page

---

Kindly suggest how we can resolve this error without changing the AD query so as to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it looks like the server you're addressing is something.com? Eg you're trying to query the entire domain rather than a specific server. Annoyingly that doesn't work as it expects a specific server. The work around I found is to add something like this at the beginning of the script.

```
$dcServer = get-addomaincontroller -discover -domain mydomain.com -forcediscover | Select-Object -expandproperty hostname
```

which can query the domain as a whole and find the DCs with it, and pick one at random. Also has the benefit that is the individual DCs change in the future the script continues to work.

After which you can run your query (and any others within the script) with the parameter listed as :

```
-server $dcServer
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case CreedSSP was disabled.
PS console:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).